# SharePoint: Using RichHTML field type in a custom content type

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

I'd like to use the field type RichHTML in a custom content type that I'm making. However, I think that the RichHTML type comes with MOSS Publishing so I'm unsure how to add it to my content type. Right now I've tried with this:

```
<Field ID="{7F55A8F0-4555-46BC-B24C-222240B862AF}" Type="RichHTML" Name="NewsBodyField" DisplayName="News Body" StaticName="NewsBodyField" Hidden="False" Required="True" Sealed="False" />

<Field ID="{7F55A8F0-4555-46BC-B24C-222240B862AF}" Type="RichHtmlField" Name="NewsBodyField" DisplayName="News Body" StaticName="NewsBodyField" Hidden="False" Required="True" Sealed="False" />
```

I know that when I want to access this custom field using a CQWP, I can export it and add it to my CommonViews using 'RichHTML', however that doesn't work here.

Any help regarding how to add a Rich Html Field to a custom content type would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out myself. The type you're looking for is "HTML" not RichHTML.